# Where does Eclipse pull ${user} from?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've had an issue since I first set up my computer where, for some reason, the last letter of my name was left out of some value. It's bugged me ever since, and changing settings on my computer hasn't seemed to fix it. I'm not exactly sure if it's my username or computer's name or what, so perhaps this will enlighten me on how to finally solve this issue.

Whenever I create new Java files in Eclipse and let it autogenerate the Javadocs, the `@author` field reads: `@author firstlas`. As I understand it, this information is pulled from the `${user}` variable inside Eclipse. I've read a lot of answers on here on how to change the default setting (which worked via editing Eclipse's .ini file), but my question is where this value is initially taken from when installing Eclipse? Is there some value on my computer that this is located at? I've tried changing some registry value before after searching for `firstlas` and corrected the value to `firstlast`, however that did not seem to change anything.

Perhaps this is more suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but I figured since Eclipse still shows me this error, someone might know where specifically the value originates from.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows the username is read from the `USERNAME` environment variable by default.

To try it out, open up a command prompt, change it with `set USERNAME=somebody`, and start Eclipse from the same command prompt.

Comment: Does that command change it forever, or just as long as that command prompt is used? I'm not sure how it was set that way to begin with, and each time I restore my computer it reverts back to `firstlas`. I've changed the default Eclipse value but would like to know how to permanently fix the issue.